# Ant design resetFields() not clearing input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I have an ant `Form` component with an `Input` component. The form is wrapped inside of a `redux` `connect()` container because I need to access a dispatch handler for one of my `Form` fields (an `Autocomplete`).

When I submit my form, I'm attempting to have the fields clear (the `Form` component should re-render because on submission I'm changing a value in the parent) and allow them to be resubmitted.

However, using the documented `this.props.form.resetFields()`, though it is clearing the form fields, is not clearing the input fields (my `Form` component still has the previously submitted fields),

relevant snippets:

**FormItem in my Form component**

```
        <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('ageYears', {
              rules: [
                {
                  validateTrigger: ['onBlur'],
                  validator: (rule, value, callback) => {
                    const isValid = (value) => {
                      const intVal = parseInt(value)
                      const validRange = range(0,30)
                      return (intVal && (validRange.indexOf(intVal) > -1)) || (intVal === 0)
                    }
                    if (!isValid(value)) {
                      callback('Please enter a valid age.', value)
                    }
                    else {
                      callback()
                    }
                  }
                }
            ],
          })(
          <Col>
            <Input placeholder="Years"/>
          </Col>
          )}
        </FormItem>
```

**submit handler**

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            const dogs = this.state.dogs.map(dog => Object.assign({}, dog));
            const idx = dogs.findIndex(i => i.active)
            this.handleUpdateDogIdx(idx, values, dogs);
          }
      });
  }
```

**setting the state of the Form component for use elsewhere**

```
handleUpdateDogIdx = (idx, values, dogs) => {
    this.setState(
      {
      dogs: dogs.map((dog) =>
        dog.active ? { ...dog, ...values, valid: true, active: false } : (
          (dogs.indexOf(dog) === idx+1) && (idx+1 < dogs.length) ? {...dog, active: true} : dog),
      )
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.props.form.getFieldsValue())
      this.props.handleDog(this.state.dogs);
      (idx + 1) < dogs.length ? this.props.form.resetFields() : this.props.handleNext(this.props.current);
      console.log(this.props.form.getFieldsValue())
    }
    )
  }
```

The last snippet produces the following objects in the console as one would expect:

pre:
`{breed: "Thai Ridgeback", gender: "female", ageYears: "2", ageMonths: "4", neutered: true}`

post resetFields():
`{breed: undefined, gender: undefined, ageYears: undefined, ageMonths: undefined, neutered: false}`

however the values in the input fields themselves haven't changed at all.

I've attempted calling `resetFields` after `setState`and I've also attempted using `initialValues` set to `''` but nothing so far has yielded any results. Is my `Form` component itself not re-rendering? Shouldn't it be if I'm updating state as shown here?

Comment: It's likely that your HOCs are mixed up. Can you post your full code pls?

Comment: Sure, which higher components exactly?

Comment: Looks like `(idx + 1) < dogs.length` is false

Comment: @Alex i don't think that's the case, because otherwise the `resetField` function wouldn't ever be called and the values wouldn't ever change. i think it has something to do with the mounting of props and the way ant in particular handles nested components and probably in particular stuff wrapped in redux.

Comment: @mburke05, you're right, just noticed that. Did you apply `initialValue` to input? Can you show full form codebase?

Comment: @Alex i have applied initialValue to input, other than that if i didnt apply its clearing the form values

Comment: What's the version did you use?